# SQLite3 decode values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I retrieved a database with a UTF-8 encoding. One of the columns displays mixed values of letters and symbols.

How do I decode the text: <~0K1aB7s/N`DImm1~>

Comment: can you elaborate some, and why do you tag 3 rdmsÄ?

Comment: the values are encoded, so how can I decode this to plaintext?

Comment: make a dbfild with data and what they mean we can't decode them because we don't know what has encoded them in the first place.  you present a text without telling us what it means.

Comment: I dont have a full dbfile. But if I did how could I tell the encoded for the text?

Comment: have you some rows where we can see what is what.

Comment: what I have is a username column with admin and a pwd column with <~0K1aB7s/N`DImm1~>.

Comment: Dig into the source of whatever created the database and see what it does.